# Is there a way to determine how loud is a video/sound playing in a web browser via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, for YouTube videos I can get the current volume value with

```
localStorage["yt-player-volume"]
```

But, is there a way to determine how loud (the loudness that I actually hear) the sound playing is in a web browser via JavaScript?

Comment: Depends on the sound.  There is no generic way.  Where is your sound coming from and how are you playing it?  The Web Audio API makes this easy.

Comment: If it depends, I can go with the YouTube example. How can I determine the loudness for YouTube videos? -a couple of approaches explained would be good though.

Comment: YouTube videos?  I don't think you can.

Comment: Wouldn't this be hardware dependent? How powerful are my speakers? the volume of any given device will differ.  Sorry if I don't understand the question

Comment: Assuming everyone uses the same hardware...